# Проблема с отображением emoji при выводе текста с MySQL и отправке в телеграмм

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telegram

есть проблема с некорректным отображением емоджи в телеграмме при выводе с бд. Емоджи записаны в виде \U0001f6ab (Python source code).
Текст с эмоджи отправляется через bot.send_message. В итоге в телеграмме отображаются закодированные емоджи в виде текста (\U0001f6ab). Текст хранится в поле типа text и сравнением utf8mb4_unicode_ci. Пробовал одинарные и двойные кавычки в бд, encode decode, не помогло. Надеюсь на вашу помощь. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

перед выполнением основного sql запроса, нужно выполнить SET NAMES ut8mb4. У меня сработало